# Limit the for loop returns with an if statement

Tags: conditional, forloop, limit

I've got a for loop working perfect with a limit of 5. Then I throw in the if statement to filter those entries that correspond with a global variable I have set. The problem is the if statement is after the for loop with the limit and only doing it's thing to the 5 entries and not all of the entries.\

I want to use the if statement on all the entries to return the ones I want, then limit it to 5. In another DIV I have and offset(5), so the rest go there. I hope that makes sense.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').order('articleOrder desc').limit(5).find() %}

    {% if entry.currentYear2 == currentEdition.currentYear2 and currentEdition.currentMonth2 in entry.currentMonth2 %}

        <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>

        <p>{{ entry.body }}</p>

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following you correct, you can use a [conditional in a for loop](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition) to do what you want.

So in your case, it would be something like:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').order('articleOrder desc').limit(5).find() if entry.currentYear2 == currentEdition.currentYear2 and currentEdition.currentMonth2 in entry.currentMonth2 %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's not doing anything different. I have 10 entries total. 6 meet the if statement criteria. When the limit is set at 20, 6 entries are returned. When the limit is set at 5, only 1 entry is returned when I want it to return 5.

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is in Brads answer here -> https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21046/for-loop-if-statement-then-limit?rq=1 That takes into account the amount of times a valid entry has been found....