# For loop, if statement, then limit

Tags: conditional, forloop, limit

I've created two global variables which my content creator is going to use to turn off a bunch of articles and turn on a bunch more which a slight change in the Global.  I have a page where there is a limit of 5 of these articles.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').order('articleOrder desc').limit(5).find() %}

{% for entry in entries if entry.currentYear2 == currentEdition.currentYear2 and currentEdition.currentMonth2 in entry.currentMonth2 %}
    <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>          
{% endfor %}
```

The problem with this is that the conditional only gets 5 entries to compare, and not the entire bunch. I want to first run an if statement on all the entries, then let me do a for loop with a .limit(5). I am not sure how to go about this. A conditional combined with a for loop in the same statement did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entirely possible I'm misunderstanding what you're looking for, but I think something like this should do it:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').order('articleOrder desc').find() %}
{% set matchCount = 0 %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    {% if entry.currentYear2 == currentEdition.currentYear2 and currentEdition.currentMonth2 in entry.currentMonth2 and matchCount <= 5 %}
        {% set matchCount = matchCount + 1 %}
        <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
    {% endif %}          
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfect, and I would never have figured that out on my own!

Comment: I am having the same problem with offset(5) as opposed to limit. Issue is, that I am failing to understand how your fix works, therefor I can't make it happen for offset.